# How to authorize a set of controllers without placing the annotation on each one?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, authorize, authorize-attribute

I have sets of controllers which are each used for each authorization type. For example, a class A authorization will have a set of controllers each which require class A authorization. Is there a way to place one `[Authorize(Role="Class A")]` attribute somewhere which will apply to each of those controllers without having to decorate each controller with the same attribute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can initialize those controllers derived from your base controller. namely put your attribute on a controller base class and to ensure that each controller within derived from base class.

```
[Authorize(Role="Class A")]
public class CustomBaseController : Controller{}

public class AController: CustomBaseController{}

public class BController: CustomBaseController{}
```

Comment: Plus, depending upon the number of controllers you have, you could just as easily place that pesky [Authorize] attribute at the top.  With having a base controller it seems you are going to have to mess with each controller anyways.

Comment: Yes, but using base controller is a best practice for initilazing and checking some datas for all controller. Maybe you want to use custom Authorize attribute. Also made changes on Custom Authorize attribute on a single controller is easy.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a way, make all those `A-class` controller derived from one base controller and place on it the `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
[Authorize(Role="Class A")]
public class AController : Controller 
{
    ...
} 

public class AFirstController : AController // Gets it's parent attribute
{
    ...
} 

public class ASecondController : AController // Gets it's parent attribute
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

2 or 3 responses here explained how you can do it... but you can also use [Fluent Security](https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity) to handle all controllers + Actions setup in one file. Some of the benefits (from their website):

**Code based configuration**

No attributes or xml cluttering up your code.

**Low imprint**

Fluent Security won't spread like wildfire in your application. Your configuration can be kept in a single file.

Comment: URL now defaults to a domain parking page.  Is Fluent Security still a thing?

Answer (score 3):

You can inherit from a base controller, such as

```
[Authorize(Role = "Class A")]
public class ClassARequiredController : Controller {}
```

Otherwise you'd be looking at a global filter, and by your question I assume you have multiple roles and sets so I don't think global filters are for you.

Answer (score 2):

Set the attribute on a ***Base Class*** and inherit, creating the hierarchy that best fits your scenario...