# Can the [Authorize] attribute be set globally for all controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently one puts the [Authorize] on the controller class or specific action. Is it possible to setup the [Authorize] attribute centrally for all controllers, say to prevent nonauthenticated use. Then after that one could define more specific [Authorize] attributes on specific controller such as

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin, SuperUser")]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using an action filter?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This should work (put in Application_Start):

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute() { Roles = "Admin, SuperUser" });
```

Comment: Thanks. Once this is applied globally, what will be the effect of applying [Authorize(Roles="User") to a specific action. Will it override it or extend the authorisation to "Admin", "SuperUser", "User"?

Comment: you must define AuthorizeAttribute? just placing this will return an error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Worked prefect

Comment: To do the same for a REST API, add this to WebApiConfig.Register():
config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute() { Roles = "Admin, SuperUser" });

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to have controllers inherit from a base controller class, and place the AuthorizeAttribute there.

[Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830906/how-to-authorize-a-set-of-controllers-without-placing-the-annotation-on-each-one)

You can then override the base AuthorizeAttribute on child classes with specific Roles, Users etc.

```
[Authorize]
public class BaseController : Controller{}

public class ChildController: BaseController{}

[Authorize(Role = "Role A")]
public class AnotherChildController: BaseController{}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is an intriguing reply. One could potentially have "AdminController", "UserController" as child controllers. What would the effect of adding an extra [Authorize(Roles="Role B")]. Would this override or extend?

Comment: I have since discovered FluentSecurity which I got from this same link!! :)

Comment: Just for info, your solution will suffer from the Logon requiring authentication. See my link above for resolution.

Comment: Having thought about this approach a little more, while it can be done, it feels a bit "hard codey" to be changing controller names in controller code files. I have to admit I like the FluentSecurity approach of controlling controllers from one file, and the controllers are still plain old base controllers.

Comment: This seems worse. It's much less straightforward and has the same chance of someone forgetting to inherit from the base class instead of forgetting to add an [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: @SamJolly Did you ever find a response to your first comment? I'm assuming the answer is extend -- but I'm willing to bet override is typically the desired behavior.