# How require authorization within whole ASP .NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, asp.net-mvc-5

I create application where every action beside those which enable login should be out of limits for not logged user.

Should I add `[Authorize]` annotation before every class' headline? Like here:

```
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers {
[Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller {




        public ActionResult Index() {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About() {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact() {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

or there is a shortcut for this? What if I want to change rules for one and only action in particular controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the \[Authorize\] attribute be set globally for all controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597624/can-the-authorize-attribute-be-set-globally-for-all-controllers)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Simplest way is to add `Authorize` attribute in the filter config to apply it to every controller.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

        //Add this line
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

Another way is to have all of your controllers inheriting from a base class. This is something I do often as there is almost always some shared code that all of my controllers can use:

```
[Authorize]
public abstract class BaseSecuredController : Controller
{
    //Various methods can go here
}
```

And now instead of inheriting from `Controller`, all of your controllers should inherit this new class:

```
public class MySecureController : BaseSecuredController
{
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add `AllowAnonymous` attribute when you need it to be accessible to non-logged in users.

Answer (score 11):

To build upon `DavidG`'s answer, if you need to require a certain role (in `Windows authentication`, for example, where everyone is authorized) you can do this:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute { Roles = "MyApp Access" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP was tagged with just `asp.net-mvc-5`, but for completeness, for ASP.NET Core MVC 6, if you're building controllers with views (via `builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()`), there are 2 ways you can require authorization for the whole app:

1. Set authorization policy

   ```cs
   namespace DL.Poc.Identity.Server
   {
       public class Program
       {
           public static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

               ...

               builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

               builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
               {
                   options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                       .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                       .Build();
               });

               var app = builder.Build();

               ...

               app.UseAuthorization();

               app.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "areaRoute",
                   pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");

               app.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");

               app.Run();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add authorization filter

   ```cs
   namespace DL.Poc.Identity.Server
   {
       public class Program
       {
           public static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

               ...

               builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
               {
                   var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();

                   options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
               });

               var app = builder.Build();

               ...

               app.UseAuthorization();

               app.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "areaRoute",
                   pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");

               app.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");

               app.Run();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Are you reffering to .NET 6 or something that was short lived few years ago and was caled ASP .NET MVC 6 before they switched to ASP .Net Core naming?

Comment: I am referring .NET 6 and ASP.NET Core MVC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0