# How to achieve Login authentication without memebership in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, forms-authentication

In MVC 4, I have added authentication manually , i mean, no membership stuff.

It will just take user name and password , authenticate against database.

Now, How i would allow valid(authenticate) user to interact with other controller  as i have added `Authorize` annotation on all other controller and want to restrict only authenticate user should allow to access other controlers action method.. please guide me how i could achieve this as not using membership ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

One way is to write your own custom authorization attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute  
{  
   Entities context = new Entities(); // my entity  
   private readonly string[] allowedroles;  
   public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles)  
   {  
      this.allowedroles = roles;  
   }  
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)  
   {  
      bool authorize = false;  
      foreach (var role in allowedroles)  
      {  
         var user = context.AppUser.Where(m => m.UserID == GetUser.CurrentUser/* getting user form current context */ && m.Role == role &&  
         m.IsActive == true); // checking active users with allowed roles.  
         if (user.Count() > 0)  
         {  
            authorize = true; /* return true if Entity has current user(active) with specific role */  
         }  
      }  
      return authorize;  
   }  
   protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)  
   {  
      filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();  
   }  
}
```

and then use it:

```
[CustomAuthorize(“Administrator”)  
public ActionResult SomeAction()  
{  
return View();  
}
```

See [**Custom Authorization in MVC**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/custom-authorization-in-mvc/)

Or you can write custom action filter attribute, See [**Custom Filters in MVC**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426766/Custom-Filters-in-MVC-Authorization-Action-Result)

Another way which i implemented recently is defined your own Base Controller and inheriting other controllers from that:

[How require authorization within whole ASP .NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970955/how-require-authorization-within-whole-asp-net-mvc-application/24970977#24970977)

Comment: thanks, Its all will helpful. But i want to know, does it not possible if we just simply set AUTHCOOKIE and apply authorize attribute on each controller ? `Authorize` attribute what to check to identify user is authenticated or not ?

Comment: i don't know about that but there are plenty of option i told customauth attribute, custom action filter attribute or your own base controller