# handling my unauthorized requests , with an http 200 response + custom message

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, authorize-attribute

I have the following custom authorization class inside my asp.net mvc web application, which i call before my action methods:-

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]

    public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                return false;
            //code goes here................
            if (!repository.can(ADusername, Model, value)) // implement this method based on your tables and logic
            { return false; }
            return true;


        }
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

                var viewResult = new JsonResult();
                viewResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
                viewResult.Data = (new { IsSuccess = "Unauthorized", description = "Sorry, you do not have the required permission to perform this action." });
                filterContext.Result = viewResult;

            }
            else
            {
                var viewResult = new ViewResult();

                viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml";

                filterContext.Result = viewResult;
            }

         //   base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

and i call this custom authorization before my action method as follow:-

```
    [CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Read", Model = "Accounts")]
public ActionResult Index(){
```

Currently as seen in the above code when the request is not authorized , I will return a JSON or a partial view depending on request type (if it is Ajax request or not).

And inside my code I always take care of handling the json returned from the custom authorization class inside the onsuccess script as follow:-

```
function addrecords(data) {
    if (data.IsSuccess == "Unauthorized") {

        jAlert(data.description, 'Unauthorized Access');
    }
    else        if (data.IsSuccess) {



            jAlert(data.description, 'Creation Confirmation');
    }
```

Currently my approach is working well, but I start thinking if  I should continue with the fact that I am NOT retuning 401 http response for unauthorized requests ? and instead of that I am returning an http 200 , either as json object with status = “unauthrized” or redirect to  a partial view ?

Can anyone advice ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used to do like this:

```
 if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
 {
      filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
      filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = "LogOut" };
 }
 else
 {
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Index");
 }
```

and in jquery i check in generic `ajaxError`:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(xhr, statusText, err){

    if(xhr.status == 403) {

      alert("Unathorized Request");

   }

});
```

or:

```
$.ajaxSetup({

 error: function (x, e) {

     if (x.status == 403) {

         alert("Unauthorized Access");

}

 });

});
```

In your approach you have to check in every Ajax call success the response what is coming, but in this approach in unauthorized case returning 403 code will make Ajax call fail and error callback executes and we i use to write a generic error handler for Ajax and check if status code is that what u i return then show message that it is unauthorized request.

you can see details : [**Asp.net mvc Check User is Logged In and authorized Before Access to Page**](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/08/aspnet-mvc-check-user-is-logged-in-and.html)

Comment: so you also return 200 http response instead of 401 for unauthorized requests , at least for the non-ajax requests ?

Comment: but what are the drawbacks of my approach ?

Comment: no i return 403 which will fail the ajax call and then i used to catch error function of ajax and check if returned code is 403 unathorized access

Comment: but what are the drawbacks of my approach?

Comment: in your approach you have to check in every ajax call success the response what is coming, but in this approach in unathorized case returning 403 code will make ajax call fail and we i use to write a generic error handler for ajax and check if status code is that what u i return then show message that it is unathorized request

Comment: but why you are returning 403 code and not 401 code ?, as 401 refer to unauthorized access , while 403 is forbidden which is not the case? Second question why is case of non-ajax request you are not returning 403 or 401, and you just redirect to another view?

Comment: I used to redirect on my custom page where I display error message unathorized access

Comment: You can return 401 status code in my case I,used 403 and I will edit in post

Comment: ok i see ,, but where i can define a general rule to handle all the 401 Ajax calls in one place ?

Comment: check this, hope it will help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970955/how-require-authorization-within-whole-asp-net-mvc-application/24970977#24970977