# How to control my 401 http response inside my asp.net mvc for both non-ajax & Ajax requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, authorize-attribute

I have created the following custom authorization attribute inside my asp.net mvc 4 web application.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]

    public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                return false;

            int value = 0;
            Repository repository = new Repository();

            string ADusername = httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(httpContext.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
            if (!repository.can(ADusername, Model, value)) // implement this method based on your tables and logic
            {

                return false;

            }
            return true;


        }
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

                var viewResult = new JsonResult();
                viewResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

                viewResult.Data = (new { IsSuccess = "Unauthorized", description = "Sorry, you do not have the required permission to perform this action." });
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                filterContext.Result = viewResult;

            }
            else
            {
                var viewResult = new ViewResult();

                viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml";
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                filterContext.Result = viewResult;
            }

         //   base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

what I am trying to do is to redirect all the non-Ajax requests  to a custom error page , while if the request is Ajax to return a json object, and then to display a jAlert box that contains the json data.

Inside my web.config I have the following:-

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

But I have the following question:-

1. From where I can define that when my custom authorization attribute return 401 to redirect to a view if the request if non-Ajax?. while if the request is Ajax to display a JAlert box? For the Ajax request i know that I can define an onfailure script which will display a jalert.but I want to avoid doing so for each Ajax function and to have this settings define at one place?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Currently i am doing the following ;
i have define this inside my general script :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup(

        {

        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        error: function (xhr, statusText, err) {
            alert("Error:" + xhr.status);
        }
    });

$.ajaxSetup({

        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        error: function (xhr, statusText, err) {
            alert("Error:" + xhr.status);
        }
    });
```

and inside my custom authorization i have the folloiwng :-

```
  protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

                var viewResult = new JsonResult();
                viewResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

               // viewResult.Data = (new { IsSuccess = "Unauthorized", description = "Sorry, you do not have the required permission to perform this action." });
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                filterContext.Result = viewResult;

            }
            else
            {
                var viewResult = new ViewResult();

                viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml";
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                filterContext.Result = viewResult;
            }

         //   base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
```

but currently if i click on an ajax link and i am not authorized , i will get the following response using firebug:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 403.0 - Forbidden</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;} 
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} 
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} 
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} 
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} 
a:hover{text-decoration:none;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} 
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;} 
h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0; 
}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif; 
 color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2; 
}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} 
.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} 
.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0; 
}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%; 
}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden; 
}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF; 
 background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal; 
 font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right; 
}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;} 
table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;} 
td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;} 
th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;} 
thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%; 
}#details-right th{width:20%;} 
table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{} 
.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;} 
.clear{clear:both;} 
.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;} 
--> 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"> 
  <h3>HTTP Error 403.0 - Forbidden</h3> 
  <h4>You do not have permission to view this directory or page.</h4> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4> 
  <ul>  <li>This is a generic 403 error and means the authenticated user is not authorized to view the page.</li> </ul> 
 </fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4> 
  <ul>  <li>Check the failed request tracing logs for additional information about this error. For more information, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> 
 </fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> 
  <div id="details-left"> 
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ManagedPipelineHandler</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000000</td></tr> 

   </table> 
  </div> 
  <div id="details-right"> 
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;https://localhost:44300/Rack/RackSwitch/702?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&amp;_=1407421575424</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C:\Users\...\Desktop\New folder (5)\TMS\TMS\Rack\RackSwitch\702</td></tr> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Forms</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...</td></tr> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Request Tracing Directory</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C:\Users\.....\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\TMS</td></tr> 
   </table> 
   <div class="clear"></div> 
  </div> 
 </fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4> 
  This generic 403 error means that the authenticated user is not authorized to use the requested resource. A substatus code in the IIS log files should indicate the reason for the 403 error. If a substatus code does not exist, use the steps above to gather more information about the source of the error. 
  <p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=403,0,0x00000000,7601">View more information &raquo;</a></p> 

 </fieldset> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

and no alert is going to be displayed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ajax case you can set global settings of AjaxError this way:

you just need to write this one time in your master layout or a js file and include it in master page, it will be called whenever an ajax call fails in your application:

```
$.ajaxSetup({

 error: function (x, e) {

     if (x.status == 401) {

         alert("Unauthorized Access");

}

 });

});
```

or you can write **ajaxError** event this way:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(xhr, statusText, err){

    if(xhr.status == 401) {

      alert("Unathorized Request");

   }

})
```

See here i answer it yesterday as well:
[How require authorization within whole ASP .NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970955/how-require-authorization-within-whole-asp-net-mvc-application/24970977#24970977)

For **normal (non-ajax requests)** you have to decorate the action or controller with your attribute:

```
[CheckUserPermissions]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{

return View()

}
```

Comment: thanks for the rpely , i know that i need to decorate my action method with my custom authorization, regardless if the request is ajax or not ,, is this right?? i can not get your point , as my custom authorization will be applied to all the action methods ,,, even if they return json >...

Comment: i also tried your approach in defing an ajaxSetup at my master page ,, but it did not work.. can u adivce

Comment: make sure jquery is included and wrap it in document.ready, check firebug console, or chrome inspector console for errors

Comment: jquery already loaded, but i think that problem is that all the 401 requests are going to be redirected to <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" /> as mentioned insdie my web.config. and i can not remove this because i want the system to automatically redirect to this url if i user is not logged-in ....

Comment: have you checked console?

Comment: it seesm that if my application return 401 , then it will redirect to Account\Login , regardless of what i have defined inside my custom authorization attribute...when i check using firebih , i can see that the application will do a redirect to the Accout\login , instead of displaying a jAlert. and the login page will be rendered as partial view ,, which looks horrible

Comment: is ajax call returned with success or error, in 403 it returns with error, and i handle it in error calback

Comment: i tried both 401 & 403 and all the redirectino will be gone to the Accountzlogin

Comment: but i am unable to catch this error using the $.ajaxSetup({}). and in this case i will need to update all the ajax functions i wrote to explicitly define an error: setting for them,, which is not a feasible approach...

Comment: @johnG how many times i have said that you need to write this only once it will handle all ajax call error

Comment: can you create a Dotnetfiddle to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: now if i return 403, and i call the ajax function , i checked the firebug and it will return the folloiwng : <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 403.0 - Forbidden</title> 
<style type="text/css">  .. but my ajax.Setup({}) will not hable this ...

Comment: you are doing something wrong i have this running in my two applications

Comment: what could be wrong ? i am sure my script where i define the ajax.setup is running correctly, as i display the current data & time using this script and they are still working well...

Comment: are you sure it was an ajax request?

Comment: what i am seeing is  it is going in else part of your filter, have you put breakpoint to check?

Comment: yes it is an ajax request using ajax.actionlink , i put a break point and it hits the right part inside my custom authorization method.. so it is 100% an ajax request.

Comment: I tried $(document).ajaxError instead of Ajax.setup and now it can handle the 403 error. but if i return 401 then i will be redirected to the login page. so i think if the user is authenticated , but not authorized then 403 maybe more appropriate.