# Setting session timeout in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, session-timeout

In a nutshell, I want to show loginpage when the session expires.For that I have modified some details in web.config shown below so that I can test whether the logic works.But sadly the below logic is not firing

My expectation was to go the `Login Action` in the `Account Controller` when the session expires.

Also what's the difference between the timeout in `authentication section` and `session state` section

```
<authentication mode="Forms">     
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"  timeout="1" />
</authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: [They](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement this by using custom attribute like below:

```
public class SessionTimeOutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

            // check if session supported
            if ( context.Session != null ) {
                if( context.Session["username"] == null ) {
                   context.Response.Redirect ( "~/Account/Login" );
                }
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Then you could apply this attribute to your Controllers or particular actions like this:

```
      [SessionTimeOut]
      public class HomeController : Controller
      {

      }
```

or for Action:

```
      [SessionTimeOut]
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
         return Index();
      }
```

Comment: for global use GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new SessionExpireFilterAttribute())  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423464/redirect-to-specific-page-after-session-expires-mvc4

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812994/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-sessionstate-timeout) answer, the basic difference of these timeout properties is:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">     
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"  timeout="1" />
</authentication>
```

"The Forms Authentication Timeout value sets the amount of time in minutes that the authentication cookie is set to be valid"

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

"The SessionState timeout value sets the amount of time a Session State provider is required to hold data in memory (or whatever backing store is being used, SQL Server, OutOfProc, etc) for a particular session."

Have you registered the Authorize filter in RegisterGlobalFilters ?

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

And also configured your controllers with [Authorize] annotation ?