# make apps unaccessable without login?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, authorization

I want my application accessible to authorized user only. How to do that?
Currently any user can see the data displayed by the application whether they log in or not.
I have add [authorize] to the home controller, it displayed the login, but still if the user type the route by themself, such as `/products`, they can see the product without login.
What I want is that without login, not matter which route they type the login page come up.
Should I put the `[authorize]` on all controller?
My application is **`MVC 4`**,  **`EF 5`**.

Comment: try below answer if need more help then comment..

Comment: this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970955/how-require-authorization-within-whole-asp-net-mvc-application/24970977#24970977

Comment: thank you for the link, Ehsan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer 1 :

Place attribute `[Authorize]` on every Controller this way :-

```
 [Authorize]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
```

Or Place it on every action as :-

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
   [Authorize]
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        return View();
   }
 }
```

With above code if user is not logged in then it will automatically redirect to Login Page.

---

### Answer 2 :

You can make a custom base controller and put `Authorize` attribute one time only and derive all the controllers from that custom base controller as :

```
[Authorize]
public class MyBaseController : Controller{}

public class AController: MyBaseController{}

public class BController: MyBaseController{}
```

Comment: you already answered a question yesterday, you should post that link and mark it duplicate with that question

Comment: @EhsanSajjad...yes but i think this question is slightly different from that question and user is new in mvc so showing complete example may help the user...

Comment: that one is also complete exmaple. is'nt it?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad..yes..but that question was related to making custom attribute and all..but this one is using inbuilt authentication authorization in mvc...

Comment: Thank you Exception. I thought that there must be a way to do it once in certain file or anything that I shouldn't put [authorize] on every controller. But if that's the only way, I will do it :) Thank yo.

Comment: @Tanu..your welcome..there is one more way..just see updated answer in  a few minutes..

Answer (score 0):

in App_Start ,Startup.Auth.cs , do u have ConfigurAuth methdo? there u should also have for example

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                ExpireTimeSpan = sessionSection.Timeout.Add(sessionSection.Timeout),
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            });
```