# How to deny anonymous users in asp.net core razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How would I deny anonymous users to access any of the razor pages in asp.net core other then a login page?

I tried

```
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.RootDirectory = "/";
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/Login");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a Razor Pages 2.x application, all you need to do is add  the following to your `Configure` method to prevent unauthorised users accessing any page in the Pages folder or subfolders:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
});
```

If you are using .NET Core 3, the following will do the same thing:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options => {
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
});
```

The unauthorised user will be redirected to the default login page, which is at `Identity/Account/Login`

Answer (score 3):

add attributes in controllers

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

then in endpoints you want to access anonymously

```
[AllowAnonymous] 
public ViewResult Index() 
{ 
      return View(); 
}
```

or you could create a basecontroller class

```
[Authorize]
public class BaseController : Controller 
{
    ...
}
```

then inherit it

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
```

[or as listed in this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
//sample code
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Contact");
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Private");
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Private/PublicPage");
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Private/PublicPages");
    })
```

[also here, `GlobalFilters`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22597699/2122217)

```
//listed answer
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute() { Roles = "Admin, SuperUser" });
```

Comment: The question is about razor pages, and I would like to do it in one place, not for each page

Comment: @mko added `addrazorpagesoptions` with documentation

Comment: @mko added `GlobalFilters` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22597699/2122217 but must put `[AllowAnonymous]` in loginpage

Comment: Most of those suggestions won't work in Razor Pages. There are no controllers. You can't put the `Authorize` attribute on  action methods and filters are applied in a different way in Razor Pages.