# How to add global authorize attribute to ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-authorization

I want to set `[Authorize]` data attribute to the application rather then controllers

```
[Authorize]
public class CustomerController : Controller {}
```

With this `[Authorize]` I can set authorization only for this controller; I want to set it for every controller.

So far I tried these in the `program.cs` class...

```
var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();

services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Both didn't work - it builds the app but on browser it doesn't reach to website. So how can I set this attribute globally in .NET 6 ?

```
builder.services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.add(new AuthorizeAttribute));
```

This throws an error

> Cannot resolve method 'Add(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute)'

Comment: This question was asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597624/can-the-authorize-attribute-be-set-globally-for-all-controllers

Comment: The [question asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597624/can-the-authorize-attribute-be-set-globally-for-all-controllers) is for an older version of ASP.NET MVC.  The answer won't work in ASP.NET Core 6.0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way to do this in ASP.NET Core 6.0 is a little different.  Microsoft Docs has an article that shows two ways to do this: [Create an ASP.NET Core app with user data protected by authorization - Require authenticated users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0#require-authenticated-users).

Option 1 - what the article calls "the preferred way" - add the following code to your `Program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

Option 2 - the article shows an alternative way using an authorization filter:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try these codes:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>

            {
                options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });
```