# Inheritance of Authorized Roles in controller classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, authorization, asp.net-roles, asp.net-mvc-controller

I've created controller classes to assist with Role authorization.

I have a base class `ControllersAuthorities`, which is the highest level of authority. I have created the other classes to extend each base class.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Owner")]
public abstract class ControllerAuthorities:Controller { }
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public abstract class AdminController:ControllerAuthorities { }

[Authorize(Roles = "Employee")]
public abstract class EmployeeController:AdminController { }
[Authorize(Roles = "Sales")]
public abstract class SalesController:EmployeeController { }
```

First question, will the `Owner`, `Admin` and `Employee` Roles have access to the `SalesController`?

When implementing these classes in my project controllers.
If I leave the `[Authorize]` uncommented, will this override the inherited authority Role?

```
//[Authorize]
public class AccountController:ControllerAuthorities
{
```

Comment: I updated my answer, there are some Tips that you need to know and I gathered in my post :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at `AttributeUsage` attribute of `Authorize` [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) ;

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, 
    Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
```

`Inherited= true` means that  subclasses of the class which decorated with this attribute can inherit this attribute.

`AllowMultiple=true` means that this attribute can be placed more than once on same entity.

With inherited attributes and allowed usage of same attribute your `SalesController`  can be considered as

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Sales")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Employee")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Owner")]
public abstract class SalesController:EmployeeController { }
```

And you can test this at runtime with this code.

```
var a = typeof(SalesController).GetCustomAttributes(true).ToArray();
```

**First question**, will the `Owner`, `Admin` and `Employee` Roles have access to the `SalesController`?
Inherited attributes are separated so they are applied independently.For one user to access `SalesController` , user must have all roles(`owner` ,`admin` ,`employee` and `sales`)  not one of them.

See the difference between

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Sales")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Employee")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Owner")]
public abstract class SalesController:EmployeeController { }
```

and

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Owner,Admin,Employee,Sales")]
public abstract class SalesController:EmployeeController { }
```

**Second question**: If you leave `[Authorize]` uncommented with same logic `AccountController` is like

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Owner")]
[Authorize]
public class AccountController:ControllerAuthorities{}
```

So it does not override inherited authority just creates multiple usage of authorize attribute because multiple usage is allowed for `Authorize` attribute. If `AllowMultiple` were `false` in `Authorize` attribute definiton then derived class could override the attribute in base class.

Comment: No ,what i am saying is inherited attributes applied differently so that one user must have owner,admin,employee and sales attributes to access SalesController. `[Authorize(Roles = "Owner,Admin,Employee,Sales")]` tells that user must have one of them to access SalesController.They are different.

Answer (score 4):

> will the *Owner*, *Admin* and *Employee* Roles have access to the
>   `SalesController`?

No, They can't access to `SalesController`. Inheritance makes your code like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Owner")]
public abstract class ControllerAuthorities:Controller { }
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin", "Owner")]
public abstract class AdminController:Controller { }

[Authorize(Roles = "Employee", "Admin", "Owner")]
public abstract class EmployeeController:Controller { }
[Authorize(Roles = "Sales", "Employee", "Admin", "Owner")]
public abstract class SalesController:Controller { }
```

And since `SalesController` requires additional role, named *Sales* won't be accessible. **Key to Access `SalesController`:** The user should be in All the mentioned roles.

> If I leave the `[Authorize]` uncommented, will this override the
>   inherited authority Role?

Yes, since `AccountController` derived from `ControllerAuthorities` which requires `Owner` role.

**Note that** the controllers in MVC are just classes with some additional features to handle requests. There's no difference with `class` concepts.

**Tip :** Look at the followings:

- `[Authorize(Roles = "Sales, Employee, Admin, Owner")]` allows the
  user which have **one of the roles**. In another words, This acts
  like *OR* (`||`) operation.
- `[Authorize(Roles = "Sales", "Employee", "Admin", "Owner")]` allows
  the user which have **All of the roles**. In another words, This acts
  like *And* (`&`) operation.

The last one is like your question. That's equal to the following too:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Owner")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Employee")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Sales")]
```

For more clarification than this! see [How to authorize a set of controllers without placing the annotation on each one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830906/how-to-authorize-a-set-of-controllers-without-placing-the-annotation-on-each-one)

Comment: @Heyyou *employee* etc have no access to `SalesController` since this controller requires *Sales* role too. If you plan to access `SalesController` by the *employee* role, you have to remove *Sales* role above the `SalesController` to let it.

Comment: are you sure `[Authorize]` overrides inherited attribute?

Comment: And what you are saying with inheritance `SalesController` attribute is `[Authorize(Roles = "Sales, Employee, Admin, Owner")]`. Like you said this `OR` case then any user that has one of the role in attribute definition could access that controller not need additional role in this case `Sales` . i think there is a contradiction in your answer.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi if `allowmultiple` was false then `[Authorize]` would override `[Authorize(Roles = "Owner")]` . But `allowmultiple=true` in `AttributeUsage`  of `Authorize` attribute. You can chekch this at runtime using `var a = typeof(SalesController).GetCustomAttributes(true).ToArray();`  .