# applying authorize from a common location

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have a few controllers which I've restricted with the `[Authorize]` decorator.  I now need to do this in a few different controllers, is there a central location which this can be put in?  Once in that location I can tell it which Controllers to apply that to, rather than me putting it to each individual controller file?

Comment: you can create a custom filter, but that would apply it globally

Comment: you can create baseController that has authorize attribute.Because attributes are inherited too.Even you can create hierarchy according to role authorization.See answer for more information http://stackoverflow.com/a/32803405/4293929

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
     public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
     {
           string controllerName = actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
           bool shouldAuthorize = //.. Check if controller needs authorization
           if(!shouldAuthorize)
               SkipAuthorization(actionContext);
           else if(!IsAuthorized(actionContext))
               HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
     }
}
```

Then you would apply this filter globally:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Note that the controller verification is done **inside** the custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a base controller your other controllers inherit from.  In this class apply your main authorization attribute.

```
Namespace Controllers
    <SecureAuthorizeAttribute>
    Public Class SecureController
        Inherits Controller
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then in your other controllers:

```
Public Class ViewDetailsController
    Inherits SecureController
End Class
```

This will apply `<SecureAuthorizeAttribute>` to every action in classes that inherit from `SecureController`.